# write json document to output file without converting to string in c++

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I have a JSON document object model. When I try to write it to a file, I could only convert to string and proceed with writing. Is there any way to write, without conversion to string?

The code I tried:

```
Document document;

// define the document as an object rather than an array
document.SetObject();

// create a rapidjson array type with similar syntax to std::vector
rapidjson::Value array(rapidjson::kArrayType);

// must pass an allocator when the object may need to allocate memory
rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType& allocator = document.GetAllocator();

// chain methods as rapidjson provides a fluent interface when modifying its objects
array.PushBack("hello", allocator).PushBack("world", allocator);//"array":["hello","world"]

document.AddMember("Name", "XYZ", allocator);
document.AddMember("Rollnumer", 2, allocator);
document.AddMember("array", array, allocator);

// create a rapidjson object type
rapidjson::Value object(rapidjson::kObjectType);
object.AddMember("Math", "50", allocator);
object.AddMember("Science", "70", allocator);
object.AddMember("English", "50", allocator);
object.AddMember("Social Science", "70", allocator);
document.AddMember("Marks", object, allocator);
//  fromScratch["object"]["hello"] = "Yourname";

StringBuffer strbuf;
Writer<StringBuffer> writer(strbuf);
document.Accept(writer);

std::ofstream file(path);
file << strbuf.GetString() << endl;
```

The output:

{"Name":"XYZ","Rollnumer":2,"array":["hello","world"],"Marks":{"Math":"50","Science":"70","English":"50","Social Science":"70"}}

But I need it with json format , not in a single line

Comment: This looks like a valid json format.

Answer (score 1):

That `rapidjson` library provides  [OStreamWrapper](https://rapidjson.org/md_doc_stream.html#FileWriteStream) to write to file without converting to string.

Answer (score 0):

Use of prettywriter helped solve the issue.
replacing

```
    Writer<StringBuffer> writer(strbuf)
```

with

```
    PrettyWriter<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
```

This way, able to get output in proper Json format